# How can I use a tsconfig file that isn't named "tsconfig.json" in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I want to use a custom tsconfig named "tsconfig.custom.json" in VS Code, but it seems that it only recognizes tsconfig files named "tsconfig.json". Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Not unless something has changed recently. This was explicitly not supported when the question came up on GitHub around 2 months ago. Just flip your files and put the settings you wish the IDE to respect in the default one.

Comment: yes, you are right. According to this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12463 it seems that it's in progress

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned in the comments, at the time of this writing, there isn't full support for tsconfig files named anything other than "tsconfig.json" in VS Code *yet*. See this issue on the VS Code GitHub repo: [Allow to specify the tsconfig.json filename explicitly #12463](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12463). <sup><sub>fun note: see the end of the thread to learn why you *shouldn't* pester project maintainers with non-constructive "me too" comments in their issue tickets :P</sub></sup>

You can, however, at least get autocomplete for filling in fields by telling VS Code what JSON schema to use for the file. Use the `json.schemas` setting like so:

```json
"json.schemas": [
    {
        "fileMatch": [ "*tsconfig*.json" ],
        "url": "http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    }
],
```

Adjust the glob pattern as needed.

And if your top-level tsconfig is named tsconfig.json and it [extends other tsconfigs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends) not named "tsconfig.json", support for IntelliSense based on the inherited config settings should work fine (I'm pretty sure the reason is because that functionality is handled by ts-server and not directly by VS Code).