# How by clicking ctrl + click watch original source code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an project on typescript and angular. There use library spatacus. I often need to see source code.

And how I work now:

I saw `StateUtil` from `@spartacus/core`, then opened the spartacus poject, searched `StateUtil` or for exacly `class StateUtil` and found it.

How I want:

Just like in other languages (GO or python). Ctrl + click on `StateUtil` and get source code (now i'm getting only type definition).

I know, in `node_modules` libraries are compiled, but I can download source code, and maybe there is a possible make development is comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

ts alias might solve this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "module-name": ["path to source path"]
    },
  },
}
```

webpack might use this this setting if your webpack config read alias from tsconfig.json

ts>=3.0 might use with [reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) solve this.

Comment: Hmm, when I added this path in compilerOptions, this works how i want in vscode, but... When I tried to build project, it tries to build and this path.

Comment:  do you mean your bundler would build your prj with the source code?

Comment: Yes. Because I added this path in compilerOptions. Maybe I can use two different `tsconfig.json`, one for bundler and another for vscode (for type definition), but i did not find how to do it. Only this  question with unresolved issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555474/use-custom-tsconfig-in-vs-code

Comment:  yes, i checked code of vscode [code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/e784e88a872d8d08e25b36da40150d05b582058f/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/tsServer/spawner.ts) :182;
they don't have path config for tsconfig.json, so you might change config of your bundler.
create a `tsconfig.dev.js` without paths, and a `tsconfig.json` extends  `tsconfig.dev.js`, edit your config to use `tsconfig.dev.js`,  